# EventListener for buttons

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, box2d, event-listener

I'm developing a 2D car game using Cocos2d-x and I have a problem.
I want to use Box2D to make collisions and movement managing easier, but before that I want to get my 4 buttons working.
The point is that I have something like this

**RaceScene.cpp**

```
bool Race::init() {
    //...
    auto forwardArrow = MenuItemImage::create("forward_arrow.png", "forward_arrow.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(Race::forward, this));
    forwardArrow->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));

    forwardArrow->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width - forwardArrow->getContentSize().width*1.2 ,
                            origin.y + forwardArrow->getContentSize().height));
    //...
}

void Race::forward(Ref* pSender)
{
    /*MessageBox("YOU PRESSED THE FORWARD BUTTON","Alert");*/
}
```

But I've noticed this is not the way because I can't neither press more than 1 button at a time nor change speed according to the time the button is pressed.

So I've googled and checked Cocos documentation, and everybody talks about that EventListeners but I don't find how to add it to my problem.

**I don't need to handle screen touches, I need to handle EACH button touch.**

Thanks.

Comment: For a "virtual dpad" you can't use the built-in menu system. If cocos2d-x has a CCButton like cocos2d-swift does you should use that, otherwise just use touch events, check on which button the touch is (if any) and act correspondingly.

Comment: I have 4 different MenuItemImage, one for each button. The point is: How can I distinguish when the touch has been on one button or another? I don't know how to call the proper function from the EventListener.

Comment: like I said, MenuItem* won't really work for what you try to accomplish. Regular touch events is what you'll need.

Comment: Thank you but I already know that, I said it "I've noticed this is not the way because I can't neither press more than 1 button at a time nor change speed according to the time the button is pressed.

So I've googled and checked Cocos documentation, and everybody talks about that EventListeners but I don't find how to add it to my problem." Anyway I found the solution with a bit help from Cocos forums.

Comment: I am Working on a similiar game. What i am doing is checkin the touch location and check whether it collides with my button rect added on screen as a sprite. If multiple touch is enabled the screen is bound to take multiple touches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some hours of researching and trying, as well as receiving some help from Cocos2d-x forums, I got the solution.

---

**RaceScene.cpp**

```
bool Race::init() {
    ...
    forwardArrow = Sprite::create("forward_arrow.png");
    forwardArrow->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));

    forwardArrow->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width - forwardArrow->getContentSize().width*1.2 ,
                            origin.y + forwardArrow->getContentSize().height));
    this->addChild(forwardArrow);

    ...

    auto listenerForwardButton = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    listenerForwardButton->setEnabled(true);
    listenerForwardButton->setSwallowTouches(true);

    listenerForwardButton->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(Race::onTouchesForwardBegan, this);
    // trigger when you let up
    listenerForwardButton->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(Race::onTouchesForwardEnded, this);

    Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, forwardArrow);
}

bool Race::onTouchesForwardBegan(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    Vec2 touchPoint = touch->getLocation();
    Rect boundingBoxArrow = this->forwardArrow->getBoundingBox();

    if (boundingBoxArrow.containsPoint(touchPoint)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Race::onTouchesForwardEnded(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    cocos2d::log("You touched %f, %f", touch->getLocationInView().x, touch->getLocationInView().y);
    MessageBox("YOU PRESSED THE FORWARD BUTTON","Alert");
    auto forward = MoveBy::create(1,Vec2(-5,0));
    mainSprite->runAction(forward);
}
```

---

**RaceScene.h**

```
class Race : public cocos2d::Layer {
    public:
        virtual bool init();
        cocos2d::Sprite* forwardArrow;
        ...
    private:
        bool onTouchesForwardBegan(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event);
        void onTouchesForwardEnded(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event);
        ...
};
```

Please note that you need a `listener->onTouchBegan` which `CC_CALLBACK_X` redirects to a `bool` function. When this one returns `true`, then the `onTouchEnd` function works, it doesn't when this one returns `false`.

Hope it helps someone.